# tinyMCE keeps adding a <ul> tag

Tags: tinymce

my TinyMCE keeps adding a ul tag cant figure it out, if I paste the following code into TinyMCE it will add ul tags and break my slider script. I'm using the latest version. and its just the ul tag.

**Paste In:**

```
  <div class="bxslider">
    <li><img style="border-radius: 0;" src="pics/slider/Image1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img style="border-radius: 0;" src="pics/slider/Image2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img style="border-radius: 0;" src="pics/slider/Image3.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img style="border-radius: 0;" src="pics/slider/Image4.jpg" /></li>
  </div>
```

**Tiny Output:**

```
<div class="bxslider">
<ul>
<li><img style="border-radius: 0;" src="pics/slider/Image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img style="border-radius: 0;" src="pics/slider/Image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img style="border-radius: 0;" src="pics/slider/Image3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img style="border-radius: 0;" src="pics/slider/Image4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your HTML (without a `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag) is invalid HTML and TinyMCE will try to create valid, well-formed HTML.